# Filtering a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a pandas data frame  `df`  with a column  `id`  with about 5 rows. In the following code below, why do I still get the length of the filtered data frame to be 5:

```
import pickle
import gzip
import bz2
import pandas as pd
import os
import _pickle as cPickle
import bz2
from downcast import reduce    

def load(filename):
    """
    Load from filename using pickle
    
    @param filename: name of file to load from
    @type filename: str
    """

    try:
        f = bz2.BZ2File(filename, 'rb')
    except:
        sys.stderr.write('File ' + filename + ' cannot be read\n')
        sys.stderr.write(details)
        return

    myobj = cPickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return myobj

df=pd.DataFrame({"ids":[1,2,3,4,5]})
print(df.shape)
sfile = bz2.BZ2File('df_list_small', 'w')
pickle.dump(df, sfile)
```

This gives a shape of  `(5,1)` .

```
df_new= load('df_list_small')
df_new = reduce(df_new)
all_groups = {ident:df_new for ident,df_new in df_new.groupby('ids')}

ids = 1
df_test = all_groups[ids]
print(df_test.shape)
```

This below gives a shape of  `(1,1)`

So maybe it works only for certain files?

Comment: Instead of 1000, how about a sample dataframe of say, 5 rows? If I do `df=pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3,4,5]})` then `len(df[df['id']==3])`, I get  a length of 1. Please make this a fully reproducible script.

Comment: @tdelaney: I got the same thing as you using your example. Maybe reading from a pickle file is the problem? I edited my code.

Comment: I end up with (0,1) after filtering with this code.

Comment: ok it works for this case

Comment: There are cases where filtering gives you views of dataframes. And pickling that... well, I guess you'd have to have the original dataframe in there somewhere. I don't have a deep enough knowledge to know when that's problematic. Of course, it could be that you've just got a misnamed variable in your original code somewhere.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. In that the only way filtering would be the same length is if all the values were equal. If the boolean series somehow resolved to all Trues. It's really hard to give more specific information without an example that I can copy into a clean workspace and reproduce the behaviour. Because currently we have a working code snippet and a corresponding unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The filtered data frame would have the same dimensions as the original one because they are equal. If I had put a different id, then the dimension of the filtered data frame would have been different.